# TorT v. 6.0.5, mac OS 10.12; cannot connect to Tor control port

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac

Cannot connect to Tor control port.  Been this way. Tried uninstalling / reinstalling several times.  Updated mac to 10.12 .  Tried with McAfee firewall disabled and enabled.  >application support>tor browser directory not even there, I'd delete it and try again if I could.  This seems to be the answer to most questions like this, but since the directory isn't even there...  I was just beginning to explore and the whole thing quit working.  Repeat question, I know, but the standard answers don't seem to be working.  Many thanks in advance!

No log file present to post

Comment: care to share your firewall port forwarding or relevant bits of torrc ?

Comment: I haven't configured port forwarding at all, and rather than admit I have no knowledge of the second part of your question I am going to figure it out... :-)

Comment: @linuxdev2013 Thank you for having the courtesy to address my issue.  There is nothing relevant to share that I can see.  TOR Browser isn't starting AT ALL, there is nothing I can do.  Perhaps the LINUX version would allow me to access configuration offline, but in the mac version I have two options: start and quit.